# SwiftUI NavigationLink isActive from view model

Tags: swiftui

I have a MVVM SwiftUI app that will navigate to another view based on the value of a @Published property of a view model:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var showView = false
    
    func doShowView() {
        showView = true
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
          NavigationView {
             MySubView().environmentObject(viewModel)
          }
    }
}

struct MySubView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.doShowView()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SomeOtherView(),
                isActive: $viewModel.showView,
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes when I run the app it will work only every other time and sometimes it works perfectly as expected.

The cause seems to be that sometimes when the property is set in the view model (in `doShowView()`) SwiftUI will immediately render my view with the *old* value of `showView` and in the working case the view is rendered on the next event cycle with the updated value.

Is this a feature (due to the fact `@Published` is calling `objectWillChange` under the hood and the view is rendering due to that) or a bug?

If it *is* a feature (and I just happen to get lucky when it works as I want it to) what is the best way to guarantee it renders my view *after* the new value is set?

Note this is only a simple example, I cannot use a `@State` variable in the button action since in the real code the `doShowView()` method may or may not set the `showView` property in the view model.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that SwiftUI creates the `SomeOtherView` beforehand. Then, this view is not related with the `viewModel` in any way, so it's not re-created when `viewModel.showView` changes.

A possible solution is to make `SomeOtherView` depend on the `viewModel` - e.g. by explicitly injecting the `environmentObject`:

```
struct MySubView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.doShowView()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SomeOtherView().environmentObject(viewModel),
                isActive: $viewModel.showView,
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I came upon a working solution. I did add a @State variable and set it by explictly watching for changes of showView:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var showView = false
    var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func doShowView() {
        showView = true
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
          NavigationView {
             MySubView().environmentObject(viewModel)
          }
    }
}

struct MySubView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var showViewLink = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.doShowView()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SomeOtherView(),
                isActive: $showViewLink,
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.$showView
                .sink(receiveValue: { showView in
                    showViewLink = showView
                })
            .store(in: &viewModel.disposables)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. You're introducing unnecessary variables and an additional onAppear modifier. It may be working in this scenario but it's not something you'd want to use more than once as it's not reusable and IMHO harms readability.

Comment: It's very weird but works for me, too. I don't know why I cannot trigger it just with viewModel's property.